# pgfplots - filldraw disappears after adding plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I have some plots in my graph and want to mark a special area with a square.

Here's what the plot looks like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines = left, xlabel = {Player 1}, ylabel = {Player 2}, xmin = 0, xmax = 3.5, ymin = 0, ymax = 3.5]

        \filldraw [draw=none,pattern=north east lines] (200, 200) rectangle (400, 400);

        \addplot [blue, thick]{2};
        \addplot [blue, thick] coordinates {(2,0)(2,3.5)};

        \addplot [color=red, thick]{-x+3};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: graph plots without marked area]

The plots render correctly, but the area, which I marked in the picture in green by hand, doesn't appear. However, if I comment out the three addplot commands, the area magically appears:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines = left, xlabel = {Player 1}, ylabel = {Player 2}, xmin = 0, xmax = 3.5, ymin = 0, ymax = 3.5]

        \filldraw [draw=none,pattern=north east lines] (200, 200) rectangle (400, 400);

        % \addplot [blue, thick]{2};
        % \addplot [blue, thick] coordinates {(2,0)(2,3.5)};

        % \addplot [color=red, thick]{-x+3};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: graph area renders without plots]

This feels like a bug to me, but maybe I'm just missing some context to know why it isn't working. Is there a way to solve this?

EDIT: Updating the packages, adding `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` before the document and replacing the coordinates with `\filldraw (2, 2) rectangle (4, 4);` seems to do the trick.

Comment: Add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` in your preamble. The coordinates are axis coordinates and you are using xmax ymax

Comment: And welcome to Tex SX :)

Comment: @percusse `{compat=1.14}` seems to do the trick. I'm updating all the packages right now

Comment: @Philipp I just noticed that the red line doesn't even start at the right spot :o

Comment: @Philipp oh, I misread that as "Tex FX" and thought you were talking about the problems of rendering, which made me look at my graph a bit more closely. Thanks for your welcome :D

Comment: @percusse You can post it as an official answer, then I'll mark it as the solution :)